# References for Completed Tensor Product and Completed Tor

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products, book-recommendation, functors, derived-functors

I'm reading Serre's Local Algebra. And there is a topic in there I would like to read more references about before I proceed. In Chapter 5, he defines the Completed Tor as
$$\hat{Tor}_i^k(M,N):= \lim_{\leftarrow_{(p,q)}} Tor_i^k(M/M_p,N/N_q)$$
where $M_p$ and $N_q$ are certain filtrations for $M$ and $N$.

Can you recommend me some references about this topic? Thank you.